# Audio playing twice upon pressing the home button

Tags: iphone, ipad, avaudioplayer

HI guys, i am developing a ebook reader. There are some audio files which needs to be played upon clicking on a icon. The audio just plays fine for the first time.. But, when i press the home button of the app and return into the audio player, the audio is being played twice... The number keeps increasing by 1 every time i press the home button and come back to the audio player.... Please help me with ur inputs.... by debugging i found that this loop is running multiple times... Can anyone tell me the reason for it??

```
-(void)StartPlayingFileWithNotification:(NSNotification *)notifcation{
// Load the array with the sample file
NSString *f = [[notifcation userInfo] valueForKey:@"audiopath"];
NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: f];
if(fileURL == nil){
    GLogError(@"%@",@"File Not Found");
    return;
}else {
    GLogInfo(@"%@",@"Got audio file");
}
if (self.player != nil) {
    if (self.player.playing) {
        [self.player stop];
    }
    [player release];
    player = nil;
}

self.player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:nil];  
if (self.player)
{
    fileName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ (%d ch.)", [[player.url relativePath] lastPathComponent], player.numberOfChannels, nil];
    [self updateViewForPlayerInfo:player];
    player.numberOfLoops = 0;
    player.delegate = self;
    [player play];
    [self updateViewForPlayerState:player];
}
[fileURL release];
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are creating new views (or other objects) containing your audio player without checking to see if the previous one is still around and running.  You could either check on activate before creating another one, or clean up the old one when the app resigns active.

Comment: hi hotpaw2.... thanku so much for ur answer.... Can u please explain me a bit more on how to do it.... i am using a singleton object to alloc the audio file but still i couldn't find the solution..

Comment: Best to debug it yourself.  Try putting a debugger breakpoint in the routines that allocate the audio player and play the sound.  See what's calling these routines and when.

Comment: i tried to debug the code by breakpoint and found that the loop in which the audio file is being assigned is running multiple times... Can u please tell me the instances  this might happen????

Comment: i have also updated my question with my code... Please give a minute for that code if u are free... thanq hotpaw2

Comment: You need to find out what's calling this code, when and why.  Use the debugger stack trace.

Comment: Hi hotpaw...... i debugged the code and found that a notification to start the audio player is being generated twice... i could not think of a mechanism to stop the notification. So, i'v changed my entire logic and now it seems to be working fine.... But, thank u so much for your intrest and help in this regard.... Cheers..